# TypeError when encrypting data using the WebAPI window.crypto.subtle.encrypt()

Tags: javascript, firefox, encryption, cryptography, webcrypto-api

I ran into a problem when I tried to use the Crypto API on firefox. ([doc](https://w3c.github.io/webcrypto/Overview.html)) 
I get a TypeError when I try to encrypt a clear text using this function :

```
window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(algo_enc,key,padded_clear_txt);
```

([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/encrypt))

This is how I defined my parameters:

algo_enc:

```
var iv = new Int32Array(4) ;//4-32 bit integers (128 bits)    
window.crypto.getRandomValues(iv); //defining the IV
var algo_enc = {"name": "AES-CBC", iv}
```

key:

```
var alg_key = {"name":"AES-CBC","length":128};   
var key = window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(alg_key,false,["encrypt","decrypt"]);
```

padded-clear-txt is a 256 bits (2*128) message that I want to encrypt.

This is the error I get when I execute the encrypt function :

> Argument 2 of SubtleCrypto.encrypt does not implement interface CryptoKey.

The generation of the key went well, and it's a CryptoKey object, but I still get this error. So maybe this is a bug I should report...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WebCrypto functions return  Promises. They are not synchronous. The result is received in a callback. See this [full example](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples/blob/master/README.md#aes-cbc)

```
window.crypto.subtle.generateKey( { name: "AES-CBC", length: 128 }, false,  ["encrypt", "decrypt"] )
.then(function(key){
    var iv  = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16))
    window.crypto.subtle.encrypt({ name: "AES-CBC",iv: iv,}, key, dataToEncrypt )
    .then(function(encrypted){
        //returns an ArrayBuffer containing the encrypted data
    }).catch(function(err){
       console.error(err);
    });     
}).catch(function(err){
    console.error(err);
});
```

Note that webcrypto uses ArrayBuffer for input and output data